# LXQt install taskbar with start button

Tags: lxqt

I have just installed LXQt on Ubuntu server 16.04 like this:

First i have installed ubuntu server from scratch, logged in as a user ubuntu and then i run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install xinit
sudo apt install lxqt-core
sudo apt install xdm
```

and now if i run `sudo startx` after login i get into GUI but there are 2 problems

```
1. screen is black and it's openbox gui
  - I can right click and I get a menu with some options
2. there is no taskbar menu with "start button"
```

I would like to get into LXQt desktop environment with taskbar and a start button.

What else do I need to install or configure to make it work?

Comment: How come no one knows this?

Comment: Why don't you run xdm to see if it can load your DE correctly?

Comment: When I run sudo xdm nothing happens. It just jumps to next row as the command was run successfully

Comment: What is the output of: `ls /usr/share/xsessions/`? And about `xdm` I guess it's a service, you should run it using `systemctl`, for now let me know what is the output of the command.

Comment: lxqt.desktop, openbox.desktop, plasma.desktop

Comment: Do as follow: `sudo mv /usr/share/xsessions/openbox.desktop{,.bk}` then: `sudo ln -s /usr/share/xsessions/lxqt.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/openbox.desktop`. then run `startx` again see what happens.

Comment: Now I have a black screen. It's logged in but i can't do anything....and i have an ssh access so i can get into console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58343/discussion-between-ravexina-and-lewis4u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to me that your Display Manager, which is `xdm` is not doing its job. I suggest you to remove `xdm`:

```
sudo apt remove xdm
```

Then try installing `slim` instead (it's more likely to work):

```
sudo apt install slim
```

Reboot your system or use:

```
systemctl start slim
```

to run `slim's` service. now use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to change your session to lxqt.

Comment: it works now. tnx to you